# What is the 'thing' that is located under the Fairy Tail basement?

Tags: fairy-tail

In Fairy Tail episode, when Master Makarov take Gildarts to appoint him as new Master, he show something to Gildarts, and I'm so interested in it. Anybody have information about that 'thing'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: The room underground]
Lumen Histoire is located in a secret underground room in Fairy Tail's [original building](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/First_Fairy_Tail_Building). This secret is only known by Fairy Tail's Guild Master and is passed on to the new Master successively. Purehito showed it to Makarov when he became Master. Years later, Makarov showed it to Gildarts Clive when he told him that he wanted him to be next Master of Fairy Tail. According to Ivan Dreyar, Lumen Histoire is Fairy Tail's darkness, while according to Mavis Vermilion, it is Fairy Tail's light.

[Wiki link](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Lumen_Histoire)

Comment: ah, so it's called Lumen Histoire, is there's anything else to know about this secret? or is it as far the story revealed to us?

Comment: As far as i know nothing more is revealed about it.

Answer (score 2):

Originally it was said that *[Lumen Histoire](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Lumen_Histoire)* is located in the basement. This has later (in chapter 4 been revealed, not to be a *thing*, but a weapon. A weapon related to the sealed body of the first master of Fairy tail, Mavis. Therefore, more than just *Lumen Histoire*, **it is Mavis' sealed body that lies beneath Fairy Tail's [original building](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/First_Fairy_Tail_Building)**.

[image]

Quote from the wiki:

> Lumen Histoire is located in a secret underground room in Fairy Tail's original building. This secret is only known by Fairy Tail's Guild Master and is passed on to the new Master successively. Precht showed it to Makarov when he became Master. Years later, Makarov showed it to Gildarts Clive when he told him that he wanted him to be next Master of Fairy Tail. According to Ivan Dreyar, Lumen Histoire is Fairy Tail's darkness, while according to Mavis Vermilion, it is Fairy Tail's light.
>
> Later, it is revealed that Lumen Histoire is in fact the body of Mavis Vermilion encased in a crystal. Makarov also calls it the "ultimate weapon" of Fairy Tail. [source](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Lumen_Histoire)

Comment: User *diras2010* commented through edit suggestion: "Remember that the Alias of Maven is "Fairy Strategist", and is stated in the manga that when she commanded the Fairy Tail on battlefield, the Guild was unbeatable, and when Acnologia attacked the Fairy Island, the spirit of Maven was the one who casted the "Fairy Shield" to save the Guild from complete destruction, so is suspected that releasing Maven from the Eternal Slumber of the Lumen Historie should be done as 'last resort' of an impending attack so powerful that the Guild members can't be able to contain or stop"

Comment: @diras2010 I think Mavis was sealed because of a curse that had happened to her, by using the incomplete version of Fairy Law (from the spoilers of FTZero going around). The new chapter should give us some more insights to this, but I don't know why they aren't being released despite the spoilers being out for days.

Answer (score 0):

The Girl in the Crystal is the 406th chapter of Hiro Mashima's Fairy Tail. This is where you can find the answer to the main question of this thread.
It was revealed on the second to the latest chapter that Lumen Histoire is Mavis Vermillion, frozen inside a crystal.

Comment: You should state which chapter this is so that future viewers can tell. Also, it's questionable whether this actually answers the question or if it should just be an edit on one of the answers.

Answer (score -1):

here it is in Chapter 406: The girl in the crystal

> ..Mavis Vermillion 
>  [image]